# Django + Heroku + GoDaddy = SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I am having trouble connecting my Heroku App (Django) to my GoDaddy Domain. Whenever I input my domain name in the URL bar an SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT error occurs. Can someone please enlighten me on how to fix this.

Here are screenshots of my Heroku and GoDaddy settings:

Heroku Settings
https://res.cloudinary.com/nthnyvllflrs/image/upload/v1560531096/3.png

GoDaddy DNS Settings
https://res.cloudinary.com/nthnyvllflrs/image/upload/v1560531098/2.png

GoDaddy Forwarding Settings
https://res.cloudinary.com/nthnyvllflrs/image/upload/v1560531097/1.png

Comment: are u acessing using HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: I think I am using HTTPS. I am really not sure though. I am a beginner in this kinds of stuff